# TypeORM upsert - create if not exist

Tags: typescript, typeorm

Does TypeORM include some functionnality to avoid this :

```
let contraption = await thingRepository.findOne({ name : "Contraption" });

if(!contraption) // Create if not exist
{
    let newThing = new Thing();
    newThing.name = "Contraption"
    await thingRepository.save(newThing);
    contraption = newThing;
}
```

Something like :

```
let contraption = await thingRepository.upsert({ name : "Contraption" });
```

Comment: a library does this - https://github.com/danielmhanover/typeorm-upsert

Comment: it's pretty easy to create a custom repository that extends the standard one as outlined by the docs here, https://typeorm.io/#/custom-repository

Comment: Thanks @danielmhanover for sharing. That repo has a fork that is more popular, that supports bulk upsert - https://github.com/lupu60/nestjs-toolbox

Answer (score 69, accepted):

As pointed out by [Tomer Amir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1678659/tomer-amir), there is currently a partial solution for **real upsert** and a feature request is ATM opened on TypeORM's repository :

[TypeORM upsert feature request](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1090)

Partial solution :

```
await connection.createQueryBuilder()
        .insert()
        .into(Post)
        .values(post2)
        .onConflict(`("id") DO NOTHING`)
        .execute();

await connection.createQueryBuilder()
        .insert()
        .into(Post)
        .values(post2)
        .onConflict(`("id") DO UPDATE SET "title" = :title`)
        .setParameter("title", post2.title)
        .execute();
```

---

*Old answer actually points to the "update" way of doing what OP was asking for :*

There's already a method for it : `Repository<T>.save()`, of which documentation says :

> Saves all given entities in the database. If entities do not exist in
>   the database then inserts, otherwise updates.

But if you do not specify the id or unique set of fields, the save method can't know you're refering to an existing database object.

So upserting with typeORM is :

```
let contraption = await thingRepository.save({id: 1, name : "New Contraption Name !"});
```

Comment: This solution is not an actual `upsert`, it's just an `update`. Upsert is this: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1090

Comment: Yes you're right ! I'm updating the solution to point out to this feature request and the current partial solution.

Comment: @BeyondTheSea Are those two completely distinct examples, or do you need to run both when using typeorm?  To me, the first call looks like it's an insert that skips conflicting rows, and the second one is an actual upsert -- but isn't the second one sufficient on its own without the first call?

Comment: How can I specify a auto generated uuid field so that `.save` would work and not insert if the object is alredy there?

Comment: How to use `onConflict` when `values` is passed an array of records instead of a single record?

Comment: @LandonKuhn you got any solution for array of records?

Comment: @TomerAmir @BeyondTheSea apologies for my lack of understanding, but how is `.save()` different from an upsert?

Comment: It seems that `onConflict` does not work with MySQL, but `orUpdate` does: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1090#issuecomment-634391487

Answer (score 41):

For anyone finding this in 2021, Typeorm's `Repository.save()` method will update or insert if it finds a match with a primary key. This works in sqlite too.

From the documentation:

```
 /**
 * Saves all given entities in the database.
 * If entities do not exist in the database then inserts, otherwise updates.
 */
```

Comment: Is it possible to do a non-primary key? Like I have "email" thats unique. Can I do `.save({ email: 'foo', age: 29 })` so it should update the row that is with `email: foo`?

Comment: I second Noitidart's comment/question: is there any way we can do this with some unique field, not necessarily the primary key?

Comment: Could you, please, link this section of the docs?

Comment: Documentation link for anyone interested: https://typeorm.io/#/repository-api

You'll need to scroll to the "save" entry

Comment: @Noitidart Did you happen to find a solution to what you describe?

Comment: To everyone who wants to do this with a non-primary key, here's how to do it: https://www.kindacode.com/snippet/typeorm-upsert-update-if-exists-create-if-not-exists/

Comment: @aviggiano Thanks for the reply, but im looking for a solution without query-builder. It seems to me a bit too low level for a propper solution provided by an ORM

Comment: thread to follow: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/9445

Comment: @aviggiano has the best answer actually, all 3 ways combined.

Comment: If you are reading this in 2024, just switch to prisma, you'll have much less headaches.

Answer (score 28):

## 2023 Update

Now you can use `upsert` method,

```
await this.yourRepository.upsert({name: 'John'}, ['id']) // assuming id is unique
```

#### If you have a constrain made of two or more columns, do this:

First define that constraint with `Unique` decorator

```
@Entity()
@Unique('constraint_name', ['col_one', 'col_two'])
```

Then in the code you can use `upsert` method.

```
await this.yourRepository.upsert({name: 'John'}, ['constraint_name'])
```

Comment: This works for me 
But, I have to set the `conflictPaths` with details instead of just the `constraint_name`

it is like 
    `await this.yourRepository.upsert({name: 'John'}, ['col_one', 'col_two'])`

Comment: If performance is important to you, you should indeed use `upsert`. The TypeORM docs state: `Unlike save method executes a primitive operation without cascades, relations and other operations included. Executes fast and efficient INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE/ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query`

Comment: the name of the constraint gives "unknown property", passing property-names or column names gives "driverError: error: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the"

Comment: what is the response of `myRepositoy.upsert(data, ['..'])`?

Comment: The specific case of upserting on the `id` did not work for me, at least with TypeORM 0.2.41 (it works when the conflicting column is something else). I had to use the `save` method as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66240533/63209) answer.

Answer (score 26):

Use [INSERT IGNORE](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm) to ignore duplicates on MySQL and Postgres:

```
await connection.createQueryBuilder()
        .insert()
        .into(Post)
        .values(post)
        .orIgnore()
        .execute();
```

Comment: It's not only on MySQL, Postgres works as well.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since `onConflict` is marked as deprecated

Answer (score 17):

this might help when `ONCONFLICT` doesn't work with MySQL. From [Github](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1090#issuecomment-634391487)

```
await getConnection()
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .insert()
  .into(GroupEntity)
  .values(updatedGroups)
  .orUpdate({ conflict_target: ['id'], overwrite: ['name', 'parentId', 'web', 'avatar', 'description'] })
  .execute();
```

Comment: This answer must be accepted as the correct one. It's the best!

Comment: @CassioSeffrin not really. The question doesn't state that it is about MySQL. It could be about PostgreSQL as well. The best answer is the one with the use of `upsert` method.

Answer (score 12):

For anyone looking for a way to upsert multiple records and is using Postgres and TypeORM, you're able to access the row you're attempting to update/insert via the excluded keyword.

```
const posts = [{ id: 1, title: "First Post" }, { id: 2, title: "Second Post" }];

await connection.createQueryBuilder()
        .insert()
        .into(Post)
        .values(posts)
        .onConflict(`("id") DO UPDATE SET "title" = excluded."title"`)
        .execute();
```

Comment: `onConflict` method is marked as deprecated, check out answer from Moshe Simantov https://stackoverflow.com/a/63678950/3984428

Answer (score 10):

This works for me.

I combined the answer from [@DedaDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3667121/dedadev).

Your entity

```
@Entity()
@Unique('constraint_name', ['id'])
```

Your service

```
await this.yourRepository.upsert(
  {
    id: uuid,
    key1: value1,
    ...
  },
  {
    skipUpdateIfNoValuesChanged: true, // If true, postgres will skip the update if no values would be changed (reduces writes)
    conflictPaths: ['id'], // column(s) name that you would like to ON CONFLICT
  },
);
```

Answer (score 5):

2021 answer: v0.2.40 added native upsert support to TypeORM

[https://typeorm.io/#/repository-api#:~:text=upsert%20-%20Inserts%20a%20new%20entity%20or%20array%20of%20entities%20unless%20they%20already%20exist%20in%20which%20case%20they%20are%20updated%20instead.%20Supported%20by%20AuroraDataApi%2C%20Cockroach%2C%20Mysql%2C%20Postgres%2C%20and%20Sqlite%20database%20drivers](https://typeorm.io/#/repository-api#:%7E:text=upsert%20-%20Inserts%20a%20new%20entity%20or%20array%20of%20entities%20unless%20they%20already%20exist%20in%20which%20case%20they%20are%20updated%20instead.%20Supported%20by%20AuroraDataApi%2C%20Cockroach%2C%20Mysql%2C%20Postgres%2C%20and%20Sqlite%20database%20drivers).

Answer (score 3):

There is now [a library](https://github.com/danielmhanover/typeorm-upsert) that plugs into TypeORM to help do this.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to checkout the "preload" method from the Repository class: [https://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/*repository_repository*.repository.html#preload](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_repository_repository_.repository.html#preload)

> Creates a new entity from the given plan javascript object. If entity already exist in the database, then it loads it (and everything related to it), replaces all values with the new ones from the given object and returns this new entity. This new entity is actually a loaded from the db entity with all properties replaced from the new object. Note that given entity-like object must have an entity id / primary key to find entity by. Returns undefined if entity with given id was not found.

As said above, the limitation is that you need to search by ID.

Answer (score 1):

In 2024, using NestJS and TypeORM, you can use [upsert](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/repository-api#upsert) and handle all edge cases.

let's say you have the entity Thing that has name and color

```js
@Entity("thing")
@Unique(["name", "color"])
export class Thing {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  color: string;

  // list goes on
}
```

And thing's `id` is used all across your database in other tables causing the infamous

> error: update or delete on table "thing" violates foreign key constraint ...

You can still use `upsert` with the detailed options

```js
await repository.upsert(
  [
    { name: "a red thing", color: "red" },
    { name: "a blue thing", color: "blue" },
  ],
  {
    conflictPaths: ["name", "color"],
    skipUpdateIfNoValuesChanged: true,
    upsertType: "on-conflict-do-update",
  }
);
```

If it is still not working, you have the bulletproof

```
const repository = dataSource.getRepository(Thing);

await repository
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .insert()
    .into(Thing)
    .values([
    { name: "a red thing", color: "red" },
    { name: "a blue thing", color: "blue" },
    ])
    .orUpdate(["name", "color"])
    .orIgnore()
    .execute();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78019622/nestjs-pgsql-typeorm-on-conflict-do-update-command-cannot-affect-row-a-second-ti

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic block to upsert the

```
async upsertRecord(createDtoGeneric, read: boolean = true) {
    const pk = createDtoGeneric.getPK()
    // enable below if pk is not auto-generated column
    // if (!createDtoGeneric[createDtoGeneric.getPK()])
    //     createDtoGeneric.initPK()
    const upsertResponse = await this._repo.upsert(createDtoGeneric, { conflictPaths: createDtoGeneric.getConflictPaths(), skipUpdateIfNoValuesChanged: true, upsertType: 'on-conflict-do-update' })
    if (read) {
        delete createDtoGeneric[pk]
        return await this.findOneByQuery(createDtoGeneric)
    }
    else
        return upsertResponse;
}
```

Comment: QueryFailedError: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row 
a second time

Answer (score -1):

Note in your entity as user here

```
@OneToMany(type => Post, post => post.user, {
        cascade: true
    })
    posts: Post[];


export const saveAllPosts = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const userRepository = getManager().getRepository(User);
    const postRepository = getManager().getRepository(Post);
    let i;
    let newUsers:any = [];
    let  newUser:any = {};
    let  newPost:any = {};
    for(i=1; i<=6; i ++) {
        newUser = await userRepository.findOne({ 
            where: { id: i} 
        });
        if(typeof newUser == "undefined") {
            newUser = new User();
            console.log("insert");
        } else  {
            console.log("update");
        }           
        newUser.name  = "naval pankaj test"+i;   

        newPost = await postRepository.findOne({ 
            where: { userId: i} 
        });
        if(typeof newPost == "undefined") {
            newPost = new Post();
            console.log("post insert");
        } else  {
            console.log("post update");
        }
        newPost.title = "naval pankaj add post title "+i;
        newUser.posts = [newPost];
        newUsers.push(newUser);     
    }
    await userRepository.save(newUsers);  
    res.send("complete");
};
```