# Typeorm insert data even if it exists

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using a node.js backend with nest.js and typeorm for database actions.
I fetch a JSON with a list of objects which I want to save in a mySQL database. This database will be updated daily but I just want to save the data which is not already in that table. I thought that `repository.save()` of typeorm does this already but it's not.

> `save` - Saves a given entity or array of entities. If the entity already exist in the database, it is updated. If the entity does not exist in the database, it is inserted.

Maybe it's because I generate a uuid column when saving and typorm think its a different item? Can someone help me with this.

```
async writeNewEPG(epgData: EpgDataDTO[]){
    const data = await this.epgDataRepository.create(epgData);
    const response = await this.epgDataRepository.save(data);
    return response;
}
```

Entity:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryColumn, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity('epg_data')
export class EpgDataEntity {

    @PrimaryColumn()
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    uuid: string;

    @Column({type: "text", nullable: true})
    sname: string;

    @Column({type: "text", nullable: true})
    title: string;

    @Column({type: "int", nullable: true})
    begin_timestamp: number;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeORM upsert - create if not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745688/typeorm-upsert-create-if-not-exist)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745688/typeorm-upsert-create-if-not-exist/58960187#58960187 Please review on above link type ORM save (insert and update work in perfect way)
you need to follow few setps :
like cascade must be true in your entity

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue befor; so I usually check first that if item exists

```
async writeNewEPG(epgData: EpgDataDTO[]){
    let oldData = await this.epgDataRepository.find(epgData);
    if (oldDate) {
        ... update data entity ( oldData.sname = epgData.sname; etc)
    } else {
        ... create new data entity ( oldData = new EpgDataEntity(); )
    }
    const response = await this.epgDataRepository.save(oldData);
    return response;
}
```

which seems like hard coding everything.
I also tried `await Repository.updateOne(oldData)` and sometimes I got unexpected errors.
Eager to find out correct answer.